# How to determine the number of resulting sets from the Cartesian Product of N sets with varying length

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for an equation to predict the resulting number of sets from a Cartesian products of N sets, with varying length. The sets look similar to as follows (but there are about 60 of them):

A=[a1, a2, a3, a4], B=[b1, b2, b3, b4, b5], C=[c1, c2], D=[d1, d2, d3, d4], E=[e1, e2]

Each product will have one element from each set (eg. [a2, b2, c2, d3, e1]) and their order does not matter (elements from a through e will remain in the same position of each set).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean to find the number of *elements* in the Cartesian product $A\times B\times\cdots\times E$? If so, then said number is $\left|A\right|\left|B\right|\cdots\left|E\right|$.

Comment: I mean the resulting number of sets... In other words, how many combinations of (a, b, c, d, e) will it produce. If that is what you mean then I just multiply together the number of elements in each set?

Comment: $\left(a,b,c,d,e\right)$, where $a\in A$, $b\in B$, $c\in C$, $d\in D$, $e\in E$, is an *element* of the Cartesian product $A\times B\times\cdots\times E$, not a *set*. The number of all such $\left(a,b,c,d,e\right)$ is $\left|A\right|\left|B\right|\cdots\left|E\right|$.

Comment: $(a,b,c,d,e)$ is not a set, it is an element of the set $A\times \ldots \times E$. And yes, in general, cardinality is multiplicative with respect to cartesian product. In order to create an element $(a,b,c,d,e)$, you have $|A|$ choices for $a$. For each such $a$, you have $|B|$ choices for $b$. Then for such $a$ and $b$, you have $|C|$ choices for $c$, and so on. That's how you can infer the result.

Comment: Okay, I understand. So I just multiply the number of elements in each set to get the total number of combinations. Easy. Thanks.